# How do I remove table rows(Except the 1st row) from a populating table?

Tags: jquery

I have a table that returns results from a search.  When the user search for something else, the same results exist and the table is just populating the data without removing the previous search.  This is all on a JSON result action with no postback so the page is not reloaded.  When the page is refreshed, I get an empty table.  I tried using the following code.

```
$('searchTable').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
$('searchTable').children('tr:not(:first)').remove();
$('searchTable td').parent().remove();
```

on the following table

```
<table id="searchTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>IdNumber</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td class="name"></td>
        <td class="address"></td>
        <td class="idNum"></td>
        <td class="status"></td>
        <td class="date"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I remove the previous search results before I go to my JSON response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `#` in your [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), like this:

```
$('#searchTable tr:gt(0)').remove();
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2Y9c3/1/), without the `#` it's an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), and it's looking for a `<searchTable>` element.